# Tables & PK /FK for relational database

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to design a relational database to answer queries such as fetching order details for a particular customer ,find customer details for a particular  order and to retrieve addresses of customers .

[this is the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYRxq.jpg)

This is what i think i need to do but im not really sure

Customers (Cust_no (PK), Order_no*, Cust_name, Phone, Address, City, State, Postcode, Country)

Orders (Order_no(PK), Cust_no*, Product_no, Quantity , Unit_price, sales_rep)

Addresses (Cust_no * (PK) , Postcode (PK) ,Address,  City, State, , Country)

I will be creating tables and inserting data into the database which im hoping shouldn't be a problem  but first i need to be clear on the relations along with PK and FK

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the Order_no from the *Customer* table. Using this FK, a customer can only reference one order. Instead, use the FK in the *Orders* table. That way, any number of orders can refer to a particular customer.

Similarly, the *Addresses* table should have probably have a FK to your customers, and no address column in your customers table. (Personally, I usually prefer to just add the address columns directly into the *Customers* table.)

Also, why do you have individual address columns (city, state, etc.) in both the *Customers* and *Addresses* table? And why are you using the postal code as the FK? That means you can't have more than one customer with the same postal code.

Here's how I'd approach it (assuming a separate table for addresses):

> Customers: Id (PK), Name, Phone
>   Orders: Id (PK), CustomerId (FK), ProductId, Quantity, UnitPrice, SalesRep
>   Addresses: Id (PK), CustomerId (FK), Address, City, State, Postcode, Country

Comment: i thought of introducing the order no in the customer table so that no orders can be added in the customers table that do not exist in the orders table .. that said will it not be possible to add/reference a second order in the customer table for a particular customer using the order_no?

Comment: That makes no sense to me. If you rely solely on the foreign keys in the Orders table, then all orders for a particular customer are guaranteed to be in the Orders table. A foreign key going the other way doesn't make sense.

Comment: fair enough. thanks for editing your earlier post . more succinct now. just a small comment on the PK ID in the address table . can I just use the address column as the PK as there is no additional  attribute in the data called (Address)ID. there is just address. im assuming you were referring to Address as ID? cheers

Comment: It's best for all tables to have a primary key. If your Address column is the street, it is possible that there are duplicates. If you add an ID column, you can assure it is always unique. And, for example you could make an auto-incrementing identity so you don't even have to set it's value. I think that is best practices.

Comment: not sure if I can create a separate attribute called address ID. I have to work with the data i have been given ;) 
forgot to ask about why you have added address as the foreign key in the customers table? as it references the addresses table, while creating customers table im getting an error "table doesnt exist "   . when i come back to the customers table to add address as the FK after creating addresses table   it throws an error "missing keyword" :/ whats going wrong?

Comment: also coming back to my original task of being able to fetch data for the query "customer details for an order" how can i achieve that if i dont use order id as a FK in the customers table ?

Comment: The FK in the Customers table was a mistake. Sorry. Your data didn't include order details, but you can get all the orders for a customer by querying the orders with CustomerId set to the ID for that customer.

Comment: ok one last question mate 
In order to be able to fetch customer details for an order will this query work ?

SELECT order_no , Cust_name, Phone,  Address
FROM customers c, orders o
WHERE c.cust_no = o .cust_no 
AND order_no = 123456?

Answer (score 0):

Almost.
Your Orders have to have Customer_ID, Address_ID.
Customers don't have to have OrderID FK.Customer > Orders 1> Many.

I wouldn't include Postal code in primary key, as you may have different addresses in the same postal code for the same customer.
You can create just an index for Postal Code to speed up search.

Comment: for my dataset , the postal code is uniquely identifying the address along with cust_no as different addresses do not exist for the same postal code and customer

Comment: I'm skeptical that postal codes are unique, but do what you think is right.